# Scroll body to first item in array from A-Z toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an A-Z toggle. I'm generating an alphabetized `ul` of data from a REST API. When I click on the A-Z toggle, I want the body to scroll to the first occurrence of a list item that matches the A-Z toggle character that was clicked.

I've tried something similar the following:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">A</a>

<ul>
    <li id="Afoo">Afoo</li>
    <li id="Amoar">Amoar</li>
    <li id="Apoo">Apoo</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
foo = ['Afoo', 'Amoar', 'Apoo'];  // this is generated elsewhere in prod code

$('a').on('click', function () { 
    var alpha = $(this).text();
    var res = [];

    for (var i=0, len=foo.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (foo[i].indexOf(alpha) === 0) {
            res.push(foo[i]);
            return res;
        }
    }

    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + res[0] + "").position().top + 24}, 650);
});
```

I think the problem stems from where my `return res;` is and possibly how I'm calling `$('#' +res[0]+ '')` but I'm not entirely sure were to start troubleshooting that.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0fujrg7c)

Thanks for any help

Comment: 1. The line `return res;` is causing the function to return before it has a chance to perform the animation. Use `break;` instead. 2. There's no reason for res to be an array. 3. Check that you actually found a result before you invoke the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `break;`, Don. My thought process for making res an array was because I have a single array storing all of the data that consists of names from A-Z from the API. I was thinking splitting this into separate arrays that match whatever A-Z toggle I clicked on would make it easier to call the first name that matches what was clicked on by utilizing `res[0]` I am getting a result when I log `res[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem has to do with what you are doing inside the for loop.

Here is a fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/7w6yujaw/1/

Just replace "return res;" with "break;"

```
var foo = ['Afoo', 'amoar', 'apoo'];

$('a').on('click', function () {

    var alpha = $(this).text();
    var res = [];

    for (var i=0, len=foo.length; i<len; i++) {

        if (foo[i].indexOf(alpha) === 0) {
            res.push(foo[i]);
            break;
        }
    }

    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + res[0] + "").position().top + 24}, 650);
});
```

You could also just do this:

```
var foo = ['Afoo', 'amoar', 'apoo'];

$('a').on('click', function () {

    var alpha = $(this).text();

    for (var i=0, len=foo.length; i<len; i++) {

        if (foo[i].indexOf(alpha) === 0) {

            $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + foo[i] + "").position().top + 24}, 650);

            break;

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized this was answered in the comments. Well, better to have an actual answer for others visiting this in the future.

Comment: Great, second example seems like better usage in my case. Thanks!